# Save null Values in Cassandra using DataStax Spark Connector

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I try to save stream data into Cassandra using Spark and Cassandra Spark Connector.

I made something like the following:

Create a Model Class:

```
public class ContentModel {
    String id;

    String available_at; //may be null

  public ContentModel(String id, String available_at){
     this.id=id;
     this.available_at=available_at,
  }
}
```

Mapping Streaming content to Model:

```
JavaDStream<ContentModel> contentsToModel = myStream.map(new Function<String, ContentModel>() {
        @Override
        public ContentModel call(String content) throws Exception {

            String[] parts = content.split(",");
            return new ContentModel(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
    });
```

Save:

```
CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(contentsToModel).writerBuilder("data", "contents", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(ContentModel.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

If some values are `null` I get the following error:

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object null to struct.ValueRepr.
```

Is there a way to store null values using Spark Cassandra Connector ?

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can use Options as well for this.

Comment: Provide same more details

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra hasn't the concept of null. A column is empty or filled. I solved this issue in scala on the following way: i used the map method and checked null values. I overrode null with an empty string. That's it. Works really good.

Comment: I don't think so. I have tried to insert null values into Cassandra table using Datastax's java mapping driver and it is successful, even if the column type is int and float. And Cassandra also displays null and returns null, hence the statement "Cassandra hasn't the concept f null" is not much convincing.

Answer (score 0):

Can we know the version of your dependencies (Spark, Connector, Cassandra, etc..)

Yes, there is a way to store nulls with the Cassandra Connector. I got your example to work properly with a Simple App and a few changes (Adding Serializabe + converting your model properties to Camel Case + The relative getters and setters). I am less familiar with the Java API (you really should use Scala when doing Spark, it makes things much easier), but I was under the impression reflection on Model classes was done at the getter/setter level... Could be wrong.

**The Model**

```
public class ModelClass implements Serializable {
    String id;

    String availableAt; //may be null

    public ModelClass(String id, String availableAt){
        this.id=id;
        this.availableAt=availableAt;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAvailableAt() {
        return availableAt;
     }

    public void setAvailableAt(String availableAt) {
        this.availableAt = availableAt;
    }
}
```

**The Driver**

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("Local App");
    conf.setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    List<ModelClass> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    modelList.add(new ModelClass("Test", null));
    modelList.add(new ModelClass("Test2", "test"));
    context.parallelize(modelList);
    JavaRDD<ModelClass> modelRDD = context.parallelize(modelList);
    javaFunctions(modelRDD).writerBuilder("test", "model", mapToRow(ModelClass.class))
            .saveToCassandra();
}
```

**Produces**

```
cqlsh:test> select * from model;

 id    | available_at
-------+--------------
  Test |         null
 Test2 |         test
```

---

It's important to know the implications of how you "write" nulls, though. Generally speaking, we want to avoid the writing out of nulls because of how Cassandra generates tombstones. If these are initial writes, you will want to treat them as "Unset".

> ## Globally treating all nulls as Unset
>
> Globally treating all nulls as Unset WriteConf also now contains a
>   parameter ignoreNulls which can be set via using a SparkConf key
>   spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls. The default is false which will
>   cause nulls to be treated as in previous versions (being inserted into
>   Cassandra as is). When set to true all nulls will be treated as unset.
>   This can be used with DataFrames to skip null records and avoid
>   tombstones.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#globally-treating-all-nulls-as-unset

**EDIT:** I should clarify, internally Cassandra doesn't store an actual null value - it's just *unset*. But we can reason with Cassandra using nulls at the application level.

Comment: Running into this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getExecutorStorageStatus()[Lorg/apache/spark/storage/StorageStatus;
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:204)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra$default$5(RDDFunctions.scala:32)
  ... 53 elided

Comment: Spark version: 2.4.3

Comment: @SumitAgarwal This is an exception you see when you have an incompatible version of the spark connector against your spark version. You can check the compatibility matrix: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

Comment: Thanks that helped, Can you look into this if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659876/ignore-nulls-with-data-frame-using-spark-datastax-connector