# Ignore Nulls with Data frame using spark datastax connector

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, connector

We have a Cassandra schema with more than 50 columns and we are inserting data into it from multiple data sources by transforming the data using Spark (Data frames not rdd).

We are running into the issue of many tombstones as our data is sparse.

Already tried the `spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true` but its not working. What would be right config to not write null values in cassandra?

I am using zeppelin to run my spark code and push data to C*

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution to this:

A hint is present in the document: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md under `Setting Connector Specific Options on Datasets`
 topic.

exact code looks like this:

```
transformedData.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("header","false").option("spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls", true).mode("append").options(Map( "table" -> table_name, "keyspace" -> keyspace_name)).save()
```

Comment: I tried this, but still I am getting null values in my Cassandra table. Is there something else, that might need to be set or changed. Please suggest.

Comment: are you using primitive data types or complex data types